# c - malloc typedef'd pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Given a typedef'd ptr type, how can I access the base type?

E.g. consider an "array" of doubles:

```
typedef double* vec_t;
```

If I try to initialise like this:

```
void init_vec(int n, vec_t v){
    v = (vec_t)malloc(n*sizeof(*vec_t));
    //...
}
```

gcc doesn't exactly like that

> error: expected expression before ‘vec_t’
>
> v = (vec_t)malloc(n*sizeof(*vec_t));
>
> ```
>                       ^
> ```

What would be the proper way to do this?

I could, of course, simply write `v = (vec_t)malloc(n*sizeof(double));`, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: So... What would be `sizeof(*double*)`?

Comment: How about `v = (vec_t)malloc(n*sizeof(*v))`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You tell me. I'm trying to dereference the type definition.

Comment: @User1291 I can't tell you, because it is your construct, not mine. You can dereference references, not types.

Comment: You *do* realize that assigning to a function parameter doesn't change the corresponding argument in the caller?

Comment: `typedef`ing a pointer is in general a bad idea. It hides semantics and results in confusion (as you already notice). Just don't!

Comment: @Olaf Unless you are using a proper naming convention. Not doing it might lead to 3 and more star programming..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: For proper code, you don't use neither, but have a `struct` at some place or use a multidimensional array and not some weird "array of pointers to array of pointers ..." construct. Note the `typedef` just hides the additional star; I'd still count `MyPtrTypedef **p;` as three star pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't cast the result of `malloc()` in C. It returns a void pointer, which will be safely promoted to `vec_t *`.

Second, `*vec_t` is an attempt to dereference a type, which is semantically invalid. You need to dereference a variable of type `vec_t`. Conveniently, you have one.

```
v = malloc(n * sizeof *v);
```

Edit: As @chqrlie pointed out, the `malloc()`'d memory is immediately lost on return. The allocated address is assigned to `v`, but the calling function's copy of `v` is not overwritten.

Comment: There is a problem with `void init_vec(int n, vec_t v)`: the function cannot return the allocated pointer to the caller.  It should either take a pointer to the `vec_t`, or return a value.  It should read: `vec_t init_vec(int n) { vec_t v = malloc(n * sizeof *v); ... return v; }`

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with `void init_vec(int n, vec_t v)`: the function cannot return the allocated pointer to the caller.  It should either take a pointer to the `vec_t`, or return a value of type `vec_t`.

A simple solution is:

```
vec_t init_vec(int n) {
    vec_t v = malloc(n * sizeof *v);
    //...
    return v;
}
```

Hiding pointers behind typedefs is not recommended, it tends to make the code less readable and more error prone.  Your `vec_t` type should really be a structure that contains a `size` member for the size of the array and a pointer to `double` or a flexible array.  You could also distinguish between the allocated length `size` and the used portion `length`:

```
typedef struct vec_t {
    size_t size, length;
    double a[];
} vec_t;

vec_t *init_vec(size_t n) {
    vec_t *v = malloc(sizeof *v + n * sizeof(*v->a));
    v->size = v->length = n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v->a[i] = 0;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Finally, since `init_vec` allocates the vector, it should be given to a more explicit name such as `create_vec`, `new_vec` or `allocate_vec`.